# Is it possible to add a toleration in kube-fledged?

Tags: kubernetes

[kube-fledged](https://github.com/senthilrch/kube-fledged) provides `nodeSelector` to select the node you want the image to be cached on. But there are taints on the nodes in my cluster. Would it be possible to add a toleration in the `imagecache` manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add tolerations to the `imagepuller` Job created by the kube-flegdged controller. Looking through [the code](https://github.com/senthilrch/kube-fledged), I don't see any facility for setting that via the Helm chart (there is a `tolerations` setting in `values.yaml`, but that is used to set tolerations on the kube-fledged controller and doesn't get passed through to generated resources).

You could [modify the source](https://github.com/senthilrch/kube-fledged/blob/837f2b36307f9b3681996722d613b5c24945a203/pkg/images/image_helpers.go#L125-L128) to add custom tolerations; alternatively, you could look into creating a [mutating web hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) that would perform the modification when the resources are created.

Comment: Yeah, adding the toleration in the values of helm chart works.